# allowing to type in datatable search button after table refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

My application is using datatable in which I am refreshing the table for every 25 seconds. If User types in the search text just a moment before the 25 seconds update time due to flickering the cursor inside search text box is losing its focus inside text box. 
How to avoid this??

Answer (score 0):

Rather than updating everything, just update the table itself. That way the textbox won't lose focus. If you must update everything, then you can call `$("#mySearchBoxId").focus()` after you refresh everything.